# Stuck web scraping with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate a web scraper using VBA to gather price data on certain items. I'm quite new to VBA and have been trying to use answers on similar topics from here to base my code but am stuck because of a "type mismatch". I have this to open IE which works fine:

```
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .Navigate "https://grocery.walmart.com/"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

However, I am now hoping to find the prices, i.e. the $1.67 for Colgate and the 
$2.78 for Nature Valley in the code below:

```html
<span data-automation-id="items">
<div class="CartItem__itemContainer___3vA-E" tabindex="-1" data-automation-id="cartItem">
<div class="CartItem__itemInfo___3rgQd">
<span class="TileImage__tileImage___35CNo">
<div class="TileImage__imageContainer___tlQZb">
<img alt="1 of C, o" src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/36829cef-43f2-4d21-9d5e-10aa9def01dd_7.04089903cc0038b3dac3c204ef7e417e.png?odnHeight=150&amp;odnWidth=150&amp;odnBg=ffffff" class="TileImage__image___3MrIo" data-automation-id="image" aria-hidden="true">
</div><span data-automation-id="quantity" class="TileImage__quantity___1rgG4 hidden__audiblyHidden___RoAkK" role="button" aria-label="1 of C, select to change quantities">
1</span></span><div class="CartItem__name___2RJs5">
<div data-automation-id="name" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="C button, Select to change quantities">
Colgate Cavity Protection Fluoride Toothpaste - 6 oz</div><span data-automation-id="list-price" class="ListPrice__listPrice___1x8TM" aria-label="1 dollar and 67 cents  each">
$1.67 each</span><a class="CartItem__detailsLink___2ts9b" aria-label="Colgate Cavity Protection Fluoride Toothpaste - 6 oz" tabindex="0" href="/ip/Colgate-Cavity-Protection-Fluoride-Toothpaste---6-oz/49714957">
View details</a></div><span class="Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6" data-automation-id="price" aria-label="1 dollar and 67 cents ">
<sup class="Price__currencySymbol___3Ye7d">
$</sup><span class="Price__wholeUnits___lFhG5" data-automation-id="wholeUnits">
1</span><sup class="Price__partialUnits___1VX5w" data-automation-id="partialUnits">
67</sup></span></div><div></div></div><div class="CartItem__itemContainer___3vA-E" tabindex="-1" data-automation-id="cartItem">
<div class="CartItem__itemInfo___3rgQd">
<span class="TileImage__tileImage___35CNo">
<div class="TileImage__imageContainer___tlQZb">
<img alt="1 of N, a" src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/775482d5-a136-4ca3-9353-28646ec999c3_1.d861ce7abd9797cbafec2cd2a4b24874.jpeg?odnHeight=150&amp;odnWidth=150&amp;odnBg=ffffff" class="TileImage__image___3MrIo" data-automation-id="image" aria-hidden="true">
</div><span data-automation-id="quantity" class="TileImage__quantity___1rgG4 hidden__audiblyHidden___RoAkK" role="button" aria-label="1 of N, select to change quantities">
1</span></span><div class="CartItem__name___2RJs5">
<div data-automation-id="name" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="N button, Select to change quantities">
Nature Valley Granola Bars Sweet and Salty Nut Cashew 6 Bars - 1.2 oz</div><span data-automation-id="list-price" class="ListPrice__listPrice___1x8TM" aria-label="2 dollars and 78 cents  each">
$2.78 each</span><a class="CartItem__detailsLink___2ts9b" aria-label="Nature Valley Granola Bars Sweet and Salty Nut Cashew 6 Bars - 1.2 oz" tabindex="0" href="/ip/Nature-Valley-Granola-Bars-Sweet-and-Salty-Nut-Cashew-6-Bars---1.2-oz/10311347">
View details</a></div><span class="Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6" data-automation-id="price" aria-label="2 dollars and 78 cents ">
<sup class="Price__currencySymbol___3Ye7d">
$</sup><span class="Price__wholeUnits___lFhG5" data-automation-id="wholeUnits">
2</span><sup class="Price__partialUnits___1VX5w" data-automation-id="partialUnits">
78</sup></span></div><div></div></div>
```

My instinct (as a true beginner) is to find the div class part above and then search for the aria-label and copy the text following it, but I feel like it will be really long-winded and may end up with tonnes of errors if that div class term is repeated elsewhere on the page.

Any help on how I should proceed (and if that is a good idea or not) would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Please include HTML using the snippet tool provided (looks like a document with <> on ) not as an image. And what is the product whose price is $1.67? I  do not see that when using https://grocery.walmart.com/  .

Comment: The html code you have as an image insert using snippet tool. You VBA code was find as it was.

Comment: I have a basket already made so all I have to do is refresh the homepage and the prices update - but I'd only like to get the individual prices from said basket instead of the random items included on the front. Ah sorry about that, will try to ammend

Comment: Is this what you meant? It all came out as a block originally so tried added some spaces to it to make it easier to read but no idea if I did it correctly or not - this is only 2 items of a 30 item basket but didn't think more copies of the same code were needed

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123637/2165759) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42497065/2165759) answers, and try to adopt the code for working with [this URL](https://grocery.walmart.com/tempo?tenant=WM_TO_GO&channel=WWW&pageType=homepage&enrich=1&targeting=%7B%22site%22%3A%22gop%22%2C%22storeId%22%3A%225260%22%7D&storeId=5260&zone=zone1&zone=zone3&zone=zone4&zone=zone5&zone=zone6&zone=zone7&zone=zone8&zone=zone9&zone=zone10&zone=zone11&zone=zone12&zone=zone13&zone=zone14&zone=zone15&zone=zone16&zone=zone17&zone=zone18&zone=zone19&zone=zone20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the prices can be selected using a CSS selector targeting the class attribute:

```
[class='Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6']
```

You would apply the CSS selector via the `querySelectorAll` method of `document` which will return a `nodeList`.

You could alternatively get a collection using:

```
.document.getElementsByClassName("Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6")
```

Code outline:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .navigate "https://grocery.walmart.com/" '> Travel to homepage
        .Visible = True '< Show browser window

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop '< Wait for page to have loaded

        Dim priceList As Object, namesList As Object, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        'Code to get your basket ready
        lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1)

        Set priceList = .document.querySelectorAll("[class='Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6']")  'Select elements by their class attribute (match on basket item prices)
        Set nameList = .document.querySelectorAll("[ data-automation-id='name']")

        For i = 0 To priceList.Length - 1 '< Loop the nodeList of matched elements
            With ws
                .Cells(lastRow + i + 1, 1) = nameList.item(i).innerText '<access the name of each matched element
                .Cells(lastRow + i + 1, 2) = Now
                .Cells(lastRow + i + 1, 3) = priceList.item(i).innerText '<access the price of each matched element
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Fixed basket items:**

**Toothpaste:**

If the cart items remain fixed and the prices update in the basket over time you can track changes in toothpaste price, for example, if you use a CSS selector of:

```
.CartItem__name___2RJs5 + span
```

So:

```
Debug.Print .document.querySelector(".CartItem__name___2RJs5 + span").innerText
```

Or:

```
Debug.Print .document.querySelectorAll("[class='Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6']").item(0).innerText
```

The last one uses the class attribute to return a nodeList of all matched elements (your basket of items) and accesses the first item (toothpaste) by index 0:

[image: index]

Or you can use `.querySelector` method which will return the first match i.e. index 0:

```
Debug.Print .document.querySelector("[class='Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6']").innerText
```

---

My code is targeting the elements by using a CSS selector (page styling) to match elements on their class attribute. All your basket item prices have the class attribute `Price__groceryPriceContainer___19Jim CartItem__price___2ADX6`. So my code pulls a nodeList (a bit like an array) of elements back which have this class attribute. The length of the nodeList is traversed to access each element by index (starting from 0). The `.innerText` property returns the literal string value of the element i.e. the price.